# state_machine update another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state-machine

*I am using rails 4.1.5 and ruby 2.1.2.*

I have two models:
`event` and `record`

Pretty standard association: `event has_many records` and `record belongs_to event`.

Both `event` and `record` have a state machine. I am using the `state_machine` gem (https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine)

I'm trying to figure out a way that when an `event` is cancelled that it updates all the `records` associated and sets them to cancelled too.

I have achieved this via the controller, but I try to subscribe to the thin views, stupid controller, fat model approach and I am trying to ensure that nothing slips through the cracks...

Here is an extract from my `event` model:

```rb
state_machine :initial => :open do
 # event to handle cancelling
 # This is a final state
 event :cancel do
  transition :open => :cancelled
  self.records.each do |record|
   record.cancel
  end
 end
end
```

Obviously there's a lot of other transitions etc. but I condensed it for simplicity...

The error I get from Rails is:

```
undefined method `records' for #<StateMachine::Event:0x007f58bada9750>
```

So I'm assuming when I'm putting `self.records.each` it is making self = state machine?

Is there anyway to get around this without using observers?

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to resolve this I ended up using Observers.

To do this you need to first put the following in to your `Gemfile`:

`gem 'rails-observers'`

Then to your `config/application.rb` file:

```ruby
config.active_record.observers = :event_observer
```

In this case 'event' is the name of my model.

Then in `app/models/event_observer.rb` I added:

```ruby
class EventObserver < ActiveModel::Observer
    # Callback for :cancel event after the transition is performed
    def after_cancel(event, transition)
        # Cancel each record associated to this event.
        event.records.each do |record|
            record.cancel
        end
    end
end
```

Hope this helps someone.